# looping jquery selector with rails code in haml document

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

this is my code
`- @events.each do |event|
    $(".fc-row").find(".fc-date:contains(= event.date.strftime("%b"))")
    .css("background", "yellow");`

my expected result, every event that contains date number, automaticly add css background yellow into that element

`$(".fc-row").find(".fc-date:contains('13')").css("background", "yellow");
More..`

second problem, how to loop this in javascript haml tag
i want to insert this code into view

if u have more efficient code solutions, just tell me

thanks, sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the template? This seems to me you're mixing HTML with JS output.

Comment: You can add class say `.bg-yellow` if a condition is true while rendering the `.fc-date` element than to find the element and add the color yellow.